# From 1D problem to easier 2D problem

Tags: classical-mechanics

Here I describe an example how a 1D problem can be solved easier by considering a mathematically equivalent problem in 2D.

Problem: Find the equation of motion of particle in 1D space with the potential $V(x)=\frac{A}{x^2}$

- Normal Solution:

Conservation of energy $$\frac{m\dot x^2}{2}+\frac{A}{x^2}=E$$

then derivative, integral, maths stuffs.

- 2D solution:
  It's exactly equivalent to the radial motion of a particle in 2D space:

Consider a polar coordinate.

Conversation of energy: $$\frac{m\dot r^2}{2}+\frac{mr^2\dot\theta^2}{2}=E$$

Conservation of momentum: $$mr^2\dot\theta=L$$

Hence: $$\frac{m\dot r^2}{2}+\frac{L^2}{2mr^2}=E$$

So it's just a uniform motion of a particle in 2D space then projected on the radius line.

The interesting part is that if $A<0$ then we must set $L$ is an imaginary number to get the result.

This may be consider a mathematical trick. But I want to know if there is a generalization of this method. Maybe it would be related to Lagrange Equations and generalized coordinates.

Comment: So are you asking, "Is there a general method for simplifying difficult 1D problems into a simpler 2D problem?"

Comment: It should be: "Is there a general method for simplifying nD problems into a simpler (n+m)D problems?

Answer (score 1):

You're instincts were correct. [Generalized coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_coordinates) can be used to expand problems that are more difficult in lower dimensions. However, they also work in the other direction, taking three dimensional problems and making them one dimensional.

I don't think there is a general rule for doing these kind of substitutions. It really depends on the exact configuration of the problem.

Comment: can you describe for me, for instance, in this particular problem, how can we reproduce the deduction using generalized coordinates? or can you give me some links to related materials?

Comment: So you want to know how to tell that you should switch coordinate systems?

Comment: yes. How to construct generalized coordinates in higher dimension from a potential in lower dimension

Comment: There isn't really a set of rules to follow to know when to make these changes. Unfortunately, a lot of physics is instinct (Kind of like knowing what to guess to solve a differential equation). To learn how to construct the coordinates take a look at the wikipedia page I linked or find a classical mechanics textbook (I recommend Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor).

Comment: I understand instincts, but I just hope that there is some way to generalize this idea and even consider it homology from lower dimension to higher dimension.
of course, some ideas are brilliant, the rest are stupid :D

Comment: Practice is the only real answer I can give you here :) Grab a textbook and work some problems!

Comment: I'm sure I have practiced enough in classical mechanics :)) If there is no generalized idea I will just consider it a math trick, no more.
The fact is that solving the equations in 1D is not really that hard.

Comment: It really is just a mathematical trick. And it's really useful when a problem in 3D is extended to say 6D (spherical coordiantes + Euler angles) to make it much easier to solve. The 1D->2D solution isn't as helpful